# Remove invalid entries in nested list

Tags: python, list

I am still a bit of a beginner, and I can't figure out a good way to crack this nut.

I have a nested list of arbitrary depth.  Something like :

`sample = [[1, [2, '', [None, 5], [6]]], None]`

I need to cycle through each level of the list and remove any entries that are empty strings or None.  Aside from this, the nested list should be unchanged.

I suspect something like recursion, but I've never created a function that does that, nor can I find a good example online that fits my needs.  My attempts have been utterly ineffective.

Any help would be appreciated, as I am at a bit of a loss how to even start.

Answer (score 1):

```
def filter_null(l):
    l = l.copy()
    i = 0
    while i < len(l):
        if isinstance(l[i], list):
            l[i]= filter_null(item) # this is the recursion
        if not item: # Checks if item evaluates to False or None
            l.pop(i)
            i -= 1 # If you delete this line the following item will be skipped
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion:

```
sample = [[1, [2, '', [None, 5], [6]]], None] 
def rem_vals(r):
   return [rem_vals(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in r if i not in [None, '']]

print(rem_vals(sample))
```

Output:

```
[[1, [2, [5], [6]]]]
```

Comment: This only considers `None` and `''` and also if something like `[None]` showed up, it would erase `None` from the list but keep the empty list.

e.g.: `rem_vals([1, [None], 3])` -> `[1, [], 3]`

Comment: @RafaelSetton The OP only specified `None` and `''` as the filter criteria. Simply checking for value truthiness `if not i` is not very thorough, as it would also remove `0` and any other object whose truthiness evaluates to `False`

Comment: in that case the way you filtered is correct, but the empty list would still remain as I pointed out earlier

Comment: @RafaelSetton, which is what the OP requested.